# QTextBrowser trouble with css

Tags: c++, html, css, qt, qtextbrowser

In my application im trying to load a simple formatted text with some images into QTextBrowser. When im trying to set my image size using :

```
  <img style="width: 128px; height: 128px;" src=":/new/prefix1/Star-five.png"/>
```

The qtextbrowser is automatically modifying my html and removing "style". Is there something i do wrong? Im setting this style from form editor.

Comment: If it's just width and height, why not use `<img width=128 height=128 ... >`?

Comment: thank you. i was just adding "px" in at the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question asnwered. Need to use width height properties without "px".